# Third party library for GIS purpose

Tags: java, geolocation, javafx, geocoding, geospatial

I am running on a project where i need to create a path for my SHIP and i need to monitor the SHIP using the Lat/Long. I need to plot the SHIP in a map & check its movement every 10 seconds.

I need to code all this in java. so, is there any one who can suggest me a best way to start with. Any third party libraries that would be useful for me.

Comment: This is too broad a question for SO and recommending libraries is off topic. Are you asking about the plotting part or the AIS signal part (I assume we are talking AIS here).

Comment: i am asking about the plotting part..! i tried studying JXMapviewer. but couldn't get the required answer.!

Comment: I think you will need to provide a bit more specific information about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that Geotools is a proper starting point (see: http://www.geotools.org/). Since your task is to track a ship's route, you should also consider the Graph extension here: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/extension/graph/index.html

Comment: How will Geotools help with graphics? He is already looking at JXMapviewer, which is a slippy map Swing viewer for OSM. And what do graphs have to do with plotting  ships?

Comment: your right Mr.John. actually to be more specific, i need to develop a stand alone application using javaFX. in which i need to create a map. i need to plot a ship using the GPS(Lat/Long) value and track it periodically. i need to create a path for the ship to reach its destination. need to find if there is any other ship on its route. etc etc

Comment: Ah, my bad, you're right. I should have read the question a bit more decent.